# Programmatically format C# code in a StringBuilder

Tags: c#

I am generating some C# classes using StringBuilder.Append() and it would be great to be able to auto format the code generated instead of manually handling line returns and indentations.

For Xml, I was able to use the XDocument.Parse() method to auto format my xml code. I need a similar method but for C#. Sort of object.Parse(sb.ToString()).

Comment: This demo has a source code, perhaps you can use it: http://www.manoli.net/csharpformat/

Comment: nope.  does not exist (except as 3rd party tools)

Comment: Did you try CodeDom? (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6(v=vs.110).aspx) it is in .net framework

Comment: I don't even know what he's asking.  Can one of you guys that understand it modify the question?

Comment: @ArsenMkrtchyan - That compiles code.  It does not format it.

Comment: @KyleW - He wants a pretty print for C# code.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter that tool only seem to highlight c# code for a nice output on a webpage. Not what I'm looking for.

Comment: @ArsenMkrtchyan We had CodeDom before but with find it old and we need too much code to generate an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NArrange solved my problem! Now I need the same type of solution for razor views.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Visual Studio, you may want to look at [T4 templating](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb126445.aspx) for generating your code, which will handle your line breaks and spacing according to the template you write.

Comment: I am using T4 templating for generating multiple files from a StringBuilder. If I do sb.ToString(), my output will be using System; public class Test { private string testvar; public void SomeFunction() {} }.

I need a library or existing function that will handle line returns and indentation for me.

Answer (score 0):

Runtime T4 Text templates have [utility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126474.aspx) methods that can indent the code for you.